# xcode subversion settings to connect to network based repository

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn, ipad, version-control

I know its not the right way to go about it but in this situation we only have 2 developers and need a quick repository setup.

I have created a repository and placed it on a network server. The repository can be accessed by smb://192.168.0.99/Dev/MyApp/Repository

In xcode repositories how do create a link to this repository. I have gone from SCM -> Repositories -> Created a Repository using the + button. Just cannot successfully connect to the repository on the network folder. Currently the Scheme is set to smb, the host set to 192.168.0.99 and path set to /Dev/MyApp/Repository

But it says error: 170000 bad url passed to RA Layer. unrecognized URL scheme for smb....

How do i set the settings to connect to the network folder based repository?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use the finder to set up a connection to the smb share first

```
finder->go->connect to server
enter smb://xxxxx details
connect
```

Then you should be able to access the repository.