# Cound not check out svn with xcode 5 and Xcode Crashes if enable svn

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn, version-control, xcode5

I am not able to setup SVN in X-Code 5. Iv tried these steps:

1) Goto-Xcode-Preferences-Accounts-Add Repositories (clicking "+" sign).

2) Enter the url path of the project `https://ipaddress:8578/svn/comapny_name/projectname/iphone/`

3)Enter the credentials. At this point of time i get this error message

```
Xcode has modified the URL.
         Xcode repository accounts represent the root of the repository.
         Subpaths can be checked out from the checkout window.
```

the Repository was added successfully with the base path `https://ipaddress:8578/svn/comapny_name/`

When i checkout the project it shows authentication warning as i dont have the permission to access the base path `https://ipaddress:8578/svn/comapny_name/`

but i have permissions to access the project folder `https://ipaddress:8578/svn/comapny_name/projectname/iphone/`

**My question**

1) how can i checkout the project from the project folder

I tried to checkout from terminal by providing the full path of the folder and i got it successfully but the problem is when i open the project xcode crashes with out any warning

( i think its due to difference in the svn paths) i checked by disabling the svn then no crash

2) how can solve this

Comment: I need the solution too

Comment: Hi Krish.. Did you find any solution fo this?

Comment: @Ganesh NO i haven't found any solution. I have an idea like disable the svn and work. When you want to commit the code you copy the code in any system which contains **previous xcode version 4.5** and commit from there or use the **terminal commands to commit**. (I haven't tried yet) Please update me if you found any solution.

Comment: This might help you krish.., But not the exact solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720575/xcode-subversion-settings-to-connect-to-network-based-repository?rq=1

Comment: I've had a lot of trouble with SVN in Xcode5 as well. [I ended up with the this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650444/continuous-integration-with-xcode-bots/19957327#19957327)

Comment: Suggest you file a bug on this with Apple. The error message suggests the correct solution but will fail since the company has not given the correct credentials. Either ask the company to change the credentials or put the repo on a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue

I haven't fixed it directly

But there is an alternative to update your local working copy

Open the terminal

Navigate to your SVN directory

And type the command `svn update`

In my case, the output:

```
Updating '.':
...
...
Updated to revision 208064
```

And XCode 5 updates with the new file directly